# Type parameter lost when introducing conditional type

Tags: typescript

Consider the following types, and a function using them:

```
type Foo = 'a' | 'b';
type Bar<T extends Foo> = {foo: T};

function baz<T extends Foo>(bar: Bar<T>) {
  const t: T = bar.foo; 
}
```

The assignment to `t` works because `bar.foo` is of type `T`, no issues here.

Now say I want to extend my `Bar` type to not only accept `Foo` type parameters, but where `T` extends `Foo` return the same type as before:

(the use-case here is that I needed to extend a type without breaking backwards compatibility)

```
type Foo = 'a' | 'b';
type Bar<T> = T extends Foo ? {foo: T} : {what: 42};

function baz<T extends Foo>(bar: Bar<T>) {
  const t: T = bar.foo; // TS2322 error
}
```

Here, the assignment does not work, even though it looks like `bar.foo` would be of type T - but in fact `bar.foo` appears to be of type `Foo`.

```
TS2322: Type '"a" | "b"' is not assignable to type 'T'.   
  '"a" | "b"' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be 
    instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Foo'.  
      Type '"a"' is not assignable to type 'T'.       
        '"a"' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be 
          instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Foo'.
```

This all happens as soon as the `Bar` type is made conditional, even if the condition evaluates to the same as before.

Why is this? And how can I extend my `Bar` type to accept other `T`:s than `Foo` but still maintain that the type of `Bar<T>['foo']` equals T?

Comment: It's a missing feature, as described in [ms/TS#52144](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/52144).  And so you unfortunately cannot get `Bar<T>['foo']` to always be `T` in scopes where `T` is generic.  You'd have to make changes other than to just `Bar<T>` for it to work, but you don't want to do that (I assume it would break backward compatibility).  Does that fully address the question? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Thanks. Yes, it does cover my question. I managed to get around it somewhat by avoiding the conditional and instead using a constraint on `T` such as `type Bar<T extends Foo | SomethingElse> = {foo: T & Foo; what: 42 & T & SomethingElse;}` to have one of the two attributes expand to `never`, but it's unsafe and, well, horrible...